# Storing value in redis tracked by each instance creator

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm dealing with a challenge that is having an active user working in a feature at the time which means only 1 person can be working on it and the others have to wait that person to leave or request to join.
The major issue is that I store them in Redis but each instance must clean the keys they create when a new version gets deployed or the app simply crashes/restarts.
This instance values need to be shared across the other instances.
If the instance where the active user crashes it has to free the key so the other users can join otherwise if the value persists it will never be cleaned and would be dangling.
Another thing is that we never know when the user quits which invalidates the usage or setting an expiration on each key

Comment: Question has a broad scope. Also it has no specific technical problem. This is more or less an architectural issue. From StackOverflow, you won't get answer for such an open question. @Enigma please try to break the question down and post it here if you face any technical issue.

Comment: I understand it might be confusing but in a nutshell, I'm trying to find a scalable solution for each application instance create its values in external persistent storage and delete when the app shutdown/reboots.